# Laravel 5.3 Password Broker Customization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization, laravel-mail

Does anyone know how to override the functions used within laravel's password broker? I know the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords#resetting-views

Give information on what to do for things like views and a few surface level things but it's not clear at all really or maybe I'm not reading it enough times.

I already know how to override the `ResetsPasswords.php` Trait but overriding the functionality of the `Password::broker()` is for the next layer in.

If there is more information needed I can kindly provide some.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had to face the same issue, needed to override some of the PasswordBroker functions. After a lot of investigation on the web and many failed attempts to do so, I ended up to the following implementation:

1. Created a **CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider** inside App\Providers where I registered  a **CustomPasswordBrokerManager** instance.

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
   use App\Services\CustomPasswordBrokerManager; 
   class CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
       protected $defer = true;

       public function register()
       {
           $this->registerPasswordBrokerManager();
       }

       protected function registerPasswordBrokerManager()
       {
           $this->app->singleton('auth.password', function ($app) {
               return new CustomPasswordBrokerManager($app);
           });
       }

       public function provides()
       {
           return ['auth.password'];
       }
   }
   ```
2. In **config/app.php** commented out line:
   `//Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,`
   and added:
   `App\Providers\CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider::class,`
3. Inside App\Services folder created a **CustomPasswordBrokerManager** and copied the context of the default **PasswordBrokerManager** located at:
   Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager.php
   Then modified the function **resolve** to return an instance of my **CustomPasswordProvider** class.

   ```
   protected function resolve($name)
   {
       $config = $this->getConfig($name);
       if (is_null($config)) {
           throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password resetter [{$name}] is not defined.");
       }

       return new CustomPasswordBroker(
           $this->createTokenRepository($config),
           $this->app['auth']->createUserProvider($config['provider'])
   );
   }
   ```
4. Finally inside App\Services folder I created a **CustomPasswordBroker** class which extends default **PasswordBroker** located at:
   Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker and overridden the functions that I needed.

   ```
   use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker as BasePasswordBroker;    

   class CustomPasswordBroker extends BasePasswordBroker    
   {    
   // override the functions that you need here    
   }
   ```

Not sure if this is the best implementation but it worked for me.

Comment: This is a very similar implementation that I ended up doing. Very well explained with identification to the directories and all. +1 and marked Correct!

Comment: Just had to change the required password length for password resets. The min length of 6 characters is burried quite deep in the laravel code so that I could only change it with your answer here. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for this. I was getting stuck on with this Password Broker and Password Broker Manager mess. Seriously, I can't comprehend how they complicated something that used to be simple in such a bad way.

Also, for people doing this on Laravel 5.4 there's a slight difference for the `register` method of the service provider than what's shown here. Essentially, the `registerPasswordBroker` method should be copied as is on  `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider` except the part where you use your own custom `CustomPasswordBrokerManager` instance.

Comment: Thank you very much, it has helped me a lot!

Answer (score 6):

There are some missing things for step 1 & 3 in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42855948/2311074

**Step 1**

Probably the safest way is to simply copy the class from `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PassswordResetServiceProvider.php` to `App\Provider\CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider`and change:

1. Namespace to `namespace App\Providers;`
2. Class name to `CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider`
3. Add `use App\Services\CustomPasswordBrokerManager;` to the top
4. Inside the function `registerPasswordBroker` rename  `PasswordBrokerManager` to `CustomPasswordBrokerManager`

**Step 2.**

Besides changing the resolve method also do the following:

1. Change namespace to `namespace App\Services;`
2. Add `use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository;` to the top
3. Change class name to `CustomPasswordBrokerManager`