# Customizing Laravel Fortify's reset password functionality

Tags: laravel, fortify, laravel-fortify

I am trying to figure out how to modify Laravel (v8) Fortify's logic when looking up which user has requested a password reset. Due to the nature of our application, a user can have 2 records in the `users` table - one with a `user_type` of "creator" and one with a `user_type` of "player".

Currently, if a user has registered as a "player" before registering as a "creator", Fortify will reset the password of the "player" record and ignore the "creator" one. However, as players can reset their passwords elsewhere, this process should only be concerned with "creator" records.

Does anybody know how to force Fortify to do a lookup on the `user_type` field as well as the default `email` field when finding the appropriate user?

TIA!

Comment: you mean you need two passwords right?

Comment: if yes, you can save your password smoewhere else . for example you can create a new model name UserSimulate . it may has some columns... like : player_password , creator_password ... you can bycrypt and decrypt them...

Comment: Users may have 2 accounts in the `users` table, with different passwords potentially. I'd like to keep the passwords in the `users` table ideally, I can't see the need to separate them.

Comment: For the record, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55912660/2917183 - thank you to @BahdCoder