# Personalized password recovery laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

In a project I am using laravel and for other people's problems I have two tables:

**user:** `id, password, remember_token, person_id`

**person:** `id, name, email`

The problem is that the data needed to recover the password are in two different tables.

In the **ForgotPasswordController.php** file

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Persona;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{


    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;


    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);


        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        switch ($response) {
            case \Password::INVALID_USER:
                return response()->error($response, 422);
                break;

            case \Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
                return response()->error($response, 422);
                break;

            case \Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
                return response()->error($response, 422);
                break;
            default:
                return response()->success($response, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously I get an error that can not find the email column.

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "email" does not
>   exist LINE 1: select * from "users" where "email" = $1 limit 1 ^ (SQL:
>   select * from "users" where "email" = email@email.es limit 1)

I finally solved it by helping me with this question. [Laravel 5.3 Password Broker Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532296/laravel-5-3-password-broker-customization)

Comment: Your quotes are wrong. Where are you generating this SQL?

Comment: This sql query is generated by laravel using, I do not do it. I have corrected the quotes of the post

Comment: Laravel expects the `email` field to be in your `users` table. You're doing something unusual, and will need to customize the built-in functionality to account for that.

Comment: Yes, that's the question, what do I have to customize to work correctly?

Comment: I finally solved it by helping me with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532296/laravel-5-3-password-broker-customization

Answer (score 0):

you aren't using the [Eloquent Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) for combining the person with the user.
try replacing the `id_person` with `person_id` in your migration (seeders, model, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, in the message I've put id_person but I really have person_id. The problem is that the email and the password are in different tables ...

Comment: I finally solved it by helping me with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532296/laravel-5-3-password-broker-customization